# How to find SCOM 2012 connector ID by its name and remove it then?

Tags: c#, monitoring, health-monitoring

There is an article that describes how to  [create and remove some connector programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb437580.aspx). However it is not clear how to find some already existed connector (f.e. by name) and remove it. Is it possible to find connector ID by its name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of searching I have found the following [link](http://systemscenter.ru/opsmgr2007sdk.en/html/m_microsoft_enterprisemanagement_connectorframework_connectorframeworkadministration_cleanup_1_6b8aa9d7.htm) with the solution.